# Como obtener un id de checkbox a traves de una tabla dimanica

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Buen dia, Me pregunto como puedo obtener el id de un checkbox que esta en dentro de una tabla con datos generados desde sqlserver.

asi es como esta el disenio de la tabla:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Width="100%" cssClass="table table-responsive">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Lineas" />
                <asp:templatefield HeaderText="ALL" ControlStyle-CssClass="clase" >
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <asp:checkbox ID="csSelectAll" 
                        CssClass="gridCB" runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
                    </itemtemplate>
                 </asp:templatefield>
                <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Turno A">
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <asp:checkbox ID="csSelectA" 
                        CssClass="gridCBA" runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
                    </itemtemplate>
                 </asp:templatefield>
                <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Turno B">
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <asp:checkbox ID="csSelectB" 
                        CssClass="gridCB" runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
                    </itemtemplate>
                 </asp:templatefield>
                <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Turno C">
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <asp:checkbox ID="csSelectC" 
                        CssClass="gridCC" runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
                    </itemtemplate>
                 </asp:templatefield>
```

y asi es como lo lleno:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT fila FROM tabla", con);

            adapter.Fill(subjects);

            GridViewTable.DataSource = subjects;
            GridViewTable.DataBind();
```

entonces como se generan en automatico conforme al numero de filas que tiene la tabla en sql no controlo cual es el checkbox que selecciono

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, yo nunca he trabajado con ASP pero mi pregunta es; este script que colocaste te genera algún HTML?, si es así; podrías por favor colocar tu Tabla en HTML que te genera para así comentarte como podrás accesar a tu Checkbox...

Answer (score 1):

Te esta faltando vincular el campo de la tabla con el checkbox

```
<asp:templatefield HeaderText="Turno A">
    <itemtemplate>
        <asp:checkbox ID="csSelectA" 
        CssClass="gridCBA" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("TurnoA") %>' ></asp:checkbox>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

como observaras se define

```
Checked='<%# Eval("TurnoA") %>'
```

para que el campo bool de la tabla tilde el check si corresponde.

[Populate (bind) CheckBox in GridView from database in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-bind-CheckBox-in-GridView-from-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Nota: en este caso use Eval("TurnoA") pero deberias definir el nombre correcto del campo que vinculas a esa columna

Comment: gracias por responder, ayer intente realizar lo que me comenta, tuve algunos problemas, ya que solo me mostraba una fila, y en la pagina al darle submit te actualizaba el campo por lo que recuerdo,
Mi objetivo final es saber cual id de la tabla en sql fue seleccionado para asi enviar x datos la pagina correspondiente, agradeceria tu opinion, soy tu fan jeje, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con éste código, aunque ahí está definido que son elementos estáticos, yo lo usé con una tabla dinámica, saludos!

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marinavillada/oo2fL4hy/)